# Selenium - Skip a table

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to pull some data out of a table using Selenium. The page I am trying to pull the data from has 2 separate tables on the page, and the data I need is in the second table. I have pointed to the second table using it's ID, but I keep getting back the data from the first table. Here is the piece of code I am using to pull from the table.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("tblSBResults"));
    String date = table.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).getText();
```

I have also tried the xpath as //table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1].

And here is what the table I'm trying to pull from looks like.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>some data</td>
            <td>more data</td?
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
...
...
<table id  = "tblSBResults">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>6/9/2015</td>
            <td>More data that I need</td>
            <td>more needed data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>more etc</td>
            <td>I think you get the point</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I'm using the Java version of Selenium by the way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using // will start searching at top of page.

Try this:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("tblSBResults"));
String date = table.findElement(By.xpath("tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).getText();
```